# How to make prolong understand a connection by other relationship

Tags: prolog

My DataBase =>

```
fact(a).
fact(b).

likes(a, rain).
likes(a, snow).

likes(b, X) :- not(likes(a, X)).

human(X) :-
    not(likes(X, rain)),
    fact(X).
    
alien(X) :-
    likes(X, snow),
    fact(X).
```

Prolog question =>

```
?- human(X)

no
```

The logic here is

> likes(a, rain),

so by rule

> not(likes(b, rain)) is True AND fact(b) is True

> human(b) is No

> human(X) is No

Should be Yes but it doesnt make the connection

How can I make with prolong this check so it understands that it should return b ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just altered the order of the predicate and it seems to work know:

```
human(X) :-
    fact(X),
    \+ likes(X, rain).

?- human(X).
X = b.
```

The reason behind this is that before unification of `X` you ask for `likes(X, rain)` and you want it to be false. So prolog searches for `likes(X, rain)`, finds `likes(a, rain)` returns true, negates it and will therefore fail. Resolve the issue by adressing `fact(X)` first, so it will ask for this particular `X` and not just any value.

Comment: Since I often see you write "unificate", I'd just like to point out that the English verb is "to unify". Yes, despite the facts that the noun is "unification", and that the verb is "unifizieren" in German.

Comment: @IsabelleNewbie You caught me. My prolog education was not held in english. And I didn't even learn english in school, so I'm pretty open for pointing out my mistakes (in a friendly manner). So thank you.

Answer (score 2):

A lowercase `x` is a *constant*, so it looks for `not(likes(x, rain))`, which indeed holds, but `fact(x)` does *not* hold since there is no clause `fact(x)`, only for `a` and `b`.

As for `human(X)` (so as a variable), `not(likes(X, rain))` will *not* succeed, since there is an `X` that likes rain: `a` likes rain, hence `likes(X, rain)` can be unfied, and therefore `not(likes(X, rain))` fails. The fact that there is a `b` that does not like rain, is not relevant. Negation in Prolog is *not* constructive, it is implemented as *finite failure*: something is not true if all attempts to proof that it is true fail and these attempts are finite (otherwise we get stuck in an infinite loop).

You can however swap the `fact(X)` and `not(likes(X, rain))` clauses:

```
human(X) :-
    fact(X),
    \+ likes(X, rain).
```

If you then call `human(X)`, it will succeed with `X = b`. This works since it will first unify `X` with `a`, but that will fail for the `\+ likes(a, rain)` clause, but then it will retry by unfying `X` with `b`, and this will succeed.